# Unable to install ubuntu - ACPI PCC probe failed

Tags: linux, ubuntu, acpi

I recently bought a new computer. The first OS I installed was windows 8.1. After that I created a bootable usb drive with ubuntu 14. Unfortunatelly every time i try to boot it and install it i have te following message: [3.004448] ACPI PCC probe failed.

And it just stays like that until I restart the computer. I read somewhere that this might have something to do with the video card. I'm using nVidia. Do you know what the problem could be and how to fix it? I'm with uefi bios. Feel free to ask me to provide more information if needed. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

the same problem whith ubuntu 15.04 (vivid vervet) but then I installed with no problem from a DVD installation. Only live-USB instalation gives a problem. Still I have installed from a USB by doing this procedure:

FOR VIVID VERVET 64 BITS:

1.--Boot from USB. As soon as you see a purple screen with just two small icons at the bottom, press tab button, this will let you to a grafical menú.

2--At the bottom right of that screen you will see a menu, to get that menu displayed you have to press F6 button.

3--click enter at the option marked as "acpi=off" then press ESCAPE button to get out of that display.

4--Now you just click where it says install operating system and you are done. The problem of this method is that you are getting rid of ACPI and that will cause side efects like having to turn off your computer by pressing the off button instead of using the OS options.

FOR VIVID VERVET 32 BITS (you dont have to get rid of ACPI):

1--At first I recieve a error message: "not a COM32 image"...no problem, just click TAB button and it will give a list of commands like: live, live-install, help... the only command of that list that really works is "help", the other ones led you to a black screen with that error message: "acpi pcc probe failed" --So as I said, do not choose other options just type "help" and hit enter...

2--The weird part starts here: a menu will display, press F3. Instead of displaying a help text (as it should) it will ¡¡let you to the live-install screen!! --then you just install as usual... But not always behaves like that, sometimes it will make what it is suposed to do: display a help text and a prompt...

3--If you recieve that help text and the prompt: type the command: "install" and press enter. In both cases, will display error messages like: "no kernel found" but still after two minutes will let you to the live-install screen. This is a happy ending because you didn't have to sacrifice acpi.

If you dont want to do this weird procedures simply install from a DVD --remember that burning a live-DVD needs a diferent procedure than a USB pendrive--

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer! Unfortunately I can't even get to this purple screen... I can see only black screen with the inscription I mentioned.

Comment: I had the error "not a COM32 image" with an Xubuntu 15.10 live USB created from Xubuntu 14.04 using the package `usb-creator-gtk`. It never occurred to me to try a command! Hitting `tab` to see options, then typing `live-install` booted successfully. Thanks!

Comment: @Crash-ID I never see the purple screen either. For me it worked to just quickly tap the [TAB] key as soon as I had selected the boot option. Of course it's been 6 months since your comment, so I'm sure you've moved on.

Comment: For some reason (installing 14.04) selecting the options didn't work. I actually had to type `nomodeset` and `acpi=off` at the end of the grub boot options.